# Json's data access with angularjs on Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Hello guys I have problem..Actually I dont know hot to access some datas in json with angularjs. I just learning angularjs.

```
<div ng-controller="KurumsalYonetimCtrl">
    <p>{{model | json}}</p>
    <div ng-repeat="item in model">
        <p>{{item.Id}}</p>
        <p>{{item.Baslik}}</p>
        <p>{{item.Aciklama}}</p>
        <p>{{item.ResimYolu}}</p> /*This is PicturePath but it doesnt show*/
    </div>

</div>
```

AngularJS Controller Code

```
    var app = angular.module('KurumsalYonetimController', []);
    app.controller('KurumsalYonetimCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.model = {};
        $http.get('/KUN/KurumsalYonetim/JsonListele').success(function (data) {
            $scope.model = data;
        });
    }]);
```

JSON DATA

```
[
      {
        "Pictures": [
          {
            "history": null,
            "landTransportation": null,
            "partialManagment": null,
            "projectTransportation": null,
            "userDetail": null,
            "Baslik": "Hakkimizda Resim",
            "Kategori": "Genel",
            "Aciklama": null,
            "ResimYolu": "1b066060-d230-45d7-a7ed-fc87bf3bd7d1_profile_avatar.jpg",
            "aboutUsId": 5,
            "historyId": null,
            "landTransportationId": null,
            "projectTransportationId": null,
            "partialManagmentId": null,
            "userDetailId": null,
            "Id": 5,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "CreatedDate": "2015-07-09T02:02:44.473",
            "UpdatedDate": "2015-07-09T02:02:44.473",
            "hasPicture": false
          }
        ],
        "userDetail": null,
        "Baslik": "deneme baslik",
        "Aciklama": "deneme aciklama",
        "userDetailId": null,
        "Id": 5,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "CreatedDate": "2015-07-09T02:02:44.16",
        "UpdatedDate": "2015-07-09T02:02:44.553",
        "hasPicture": true
      }
    ]
```

I cant access Pictures in this json result, but i can access these datas.How can I access also Pictures

```
  "userDetail": null,
    "Baslik": "deneme baslik",
    "Aciklama": "deneme aciklama",
    "userDetailId": null,
    "Id": 5,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "CreatedDate": "2015-07-09T02:02:44.16",
    "UpdatedDate": "2015-07-09T02:02:44.553",
    "hasPicture": true
  }
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more code showing your current approach of using this json object?

Comment: I also add my anguarjs controller

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your success function and see that your data parameter contains what you expect.

Comment: Show us how you're trying to access Pictures

Comment: I add new code about html code

Comment: and I getting data from database as json so this json code is already come from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON looks wrong. The reason you can access the bottom part is that you're looping through an array of objects.

```
 {
        "Pictures": [
          {
            "history": null,
            "landTransportation": null,
            "partialManagment": null,
            "projectTransportation": null,
            "userDetail": null,
            "Baslik": "Hakkimizda Resim",
            "Kategori": "Genel",
            "Aciklama": null,
            "ResimYolu": "1b066060-d230-45d7-a7ed-fc87bf3bd7d1_profile_avatar.jpg",
            "aboutUsId": 5,
            "historyId": null,
            "landTransportationId": null,
            "projectTransportationId": null,
            "partialManagmentId": null,
            "userDetailId": null,
            "Id": 5,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "CreatedDate": "2015-07-09T02:02:44.473",
            "UpdatedDate": "2015-07-09T02:02:44.473",
            "hasPicture": false
          }
        ],
        "userDetail": null,
        "Baslik": "deneme baslik",
        "Aciklama": "deneme aciklama",
        "userDetailId": null,
        "Id": 5,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "CreatedDate": "2015-07-09T02:02:44.16",
        "UpdatedDate": "2015-07-09T02:02:44.553",
        "hasPicture": true
      }
```

That is all one object, which is your `item` in your `ng-repeat`. So, when you loop, it can grab that `Id, Aciklama`, etc. The reason you aren't getting the Id for Pictures is because it's a nested array of objects. You have to go another level in to get the `Id, Baslik`, etc. inside the Pictures array.

To loop the pictures, do this:
`$scope.Pictures = model[0].Pictures;` and then `item in Pictures`

Your JSON looks malformed to me.

### EDIT

After some feedback in the comments, the JSON looks like it's the way it should be. You just need to make the changes I detailed above to get the picture data in your ng-repeat.

Comment: Thank you so much this loop is worked..But I have one more question How can I fix my json result format ?

Comment: That's a little difficult to answer. Is the bottom part supposed to be a picture object? It *looks* like it's supposed to be, but you don't have the same fields in it.

Comment: Actually they have relationship (oneToMany) each other aboutUs and Picture table.So aboutUs table can have many picture but every picture can have one aboutUs

Comment: So Im getting aboutUs table from database as json.aboutUs have many picture.So the json result returning array to picture table as array json object in the aboutUs.

Comment: I would have an AboutUs property at the same level as Pictures, from what you're telling me. But, it's hard to say for sure without a good understanding of what you're trying to accomplish. If the AboutUs is information about an object and that object also has Pictures associated with it, that makes sense to me.

Comment: I add my classes as answer you can check it

Comment: @Emre Okay, after seeing your classes, that looks right. You were just accessing it incorrectly. Please delete that answer below as it's not an answer to your question. Since Pictures IS a part of AboutUs, that's what your JSON is showing. The way you explained it, I didn't think that was the case. Your JSON is fine then.

Comment: ok thank you so much for your answers you clear me up.I deleted my answer.